# "Position: Absolute" Not Displaying on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, css-position

I am working on a table that has the left column positioned absolutely; however, on iOS, the left column does not appear

Screenshot of iOS:

[image: iOS Screenshot]

The CSS that positions the left column:

```
    .leftColumn {
        position:absolute;
        width:5em;
        left:0px;
        top:auto;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2UAT6/

Has anyone encountered this before?

**Updated:** When the parent is set to `absolute`, the following render error occurs. (here is an updated fiddle)

[image]

**Goal:**
I would like to have a table with the left column fixed in place, so when the user scrolls, the left column is always present. It displays fine in desktop browsers, but does not display at all on iOS, as shown in the screenshots.

Comment: Is the parent positioned `relative`?....

Comment: No, when I position it relative, the first column becomes overlapped with the next column, and does not remain fixed in position. Do you think this is a problem with the positioning of the parent?

Comment: Usually when you position an element to `absolute`, it is advised to set the parent `position` to `relative` or `absolute`, in order for you to have better control.An absolute-positioned element align itself to the nearest positioned parent.

Comment: More relevant codes needed..

Comment: I just updated the question with a screenshot of the page when the parent div is set to absolute.

Comment: I also added a link to a fiddle that demonstrates what happens when the parent div is positioned absolute. Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not a problem with iOS or your code. The output it gives is exactly what `position: absolute;` is supposed to produce. Your problem is you're using absolution positioning when you should not be using absolute positioning. Please update your question to describe what your actual goal is, and we can suggest what CSS rules to use (most likely it will not involve absolute anywhere).

Comment: I updated the question with the goal. I would like the left column to appear on iOS devices like it does on desktop Safari. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just not make it position absolute?

Comment: The left column is position absolute. If you make the parent div position absolute, it does not appear correctly.